# push is blocked even when remote branch with name ref/for/develop was deleted

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm using git with gerrit 
and using command

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/develop
```

to push on develop branch with review (via ssh connection)
unfortunately when I have reference in git config file to remote repo with https
like this

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://
```

then command

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/develop
```

will create branch with name

```
refs/for/develop
```

Of course if something is possible then I will be

So I deleted the branch via gerrit GUI
but still can't push on review when I'm connected via ssh

```
[remote "origin"]
url = ssh://
```

even if

```
git show-ref
```

don't show this problematic branch

response from git

```
fatal: One or more refs/for/ names blocks change upload
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 2568, received 1800 bytes, in 0.5 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 5005.8, received 3508.8
debug1: Exit status 1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

When I switched once again to https
and try use the same command just to check if I will be able to create the same branch if the old one was deleted then I'm getting error

```
USER@CE19933 MINGW64 /c/repo/repo (develop)
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/develop
To https:/........git
 ! [rejected]        HEAD -> refs/for/develop (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://........git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

this is proof that not all information about this problematic branch from remote repo has been deleted

I tested also this command

```
git update-ref -d refs/for/
```

but after branch deletion from gerrit GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, is anyone else working on this branch, or are you working on it from a different repo? If so, then you need to use `git pull` first to integrate the work from the remote into your local branch.

If you're not sure what's on there and feeling concerned about the consequences of a `git pull`, then you can either create a copy of your branch for experimentation (`git checkout -b <experiment-branch-name>`) or just jot down the current commit's hash id for a later reset if your change your mind (`git reset --hard <hash-id>`).

---

**The Nuclear Option**

If **no one else is working on that branch** and **no one else has created a new branch based on that branch** then you can use `git push --force ...` to tell the origin server that you really, really want to apply this commit. **This will replace the commits on the server with your commits** which will cause weeping and gnashing of teeth if you have any colleagues working on it... so proceed with ***extreme caution***.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I pulled new changes. I was up to date.
In case of --force option didn't try this.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
What is interesting about this problem we have two domains. 
Old and new one. I'm not sure how this works. I thought there was no difference between them, and that was my mistake. 
We used old one with https, and the after later we added gerrit and switched to new domain and ssh protocol.
It wasn't possible to execute on this new ssh domain which reference to the same repo

```
git push origin --delete refs/for/develop
...a lot of debug logs
fatal: One or more refs/for/ names blocks change upload
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 
Transferred: sent 2568, received 1800 bytes, in 0.4 second
Bytes per second: sent 6997.3, received 4904.6
debug1: Exit status 1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

but when I changed the git config to the old one and https

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://
```

it was possible

```
$ git push origin --delete refs/for/develop
To https:/.......git
- [deleted]         refs/for/develop
```

after this I switched once again to the new domain and ssh protocol 
And now git push with refs/for is possible.

```
 git push origin HEAD:refs/for/develop
```

At the moment from my point of view it looks like two repository's with some kind of replication. But I'm not sure if it is possible.
I will provide further information when I find out how the repositories are organized.